# Hamilton-Jacobi method with time dependent Hamiltonian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, coordinate-systems, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space

> I have the following phase space
> $$
> M = \{ (p, q) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid q \geq 0 \}
> $$
> and the Hamiltonian $H = q^2p^2t$.
> How does one solve for $q(t)$, with $q(0) = q_0 > 0, p(0) = p_0$ using the [HJ equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi_equation)?

I tried writing the generating function $S = S(q, t) = a(t)b(q)$, as I don't think additive separation of variables works in this case. The problem here is that plugging this guess into HJ, I get two differential equations (one for $a$ and one for $b$) and hence two arbitrary integration constants. But I only need one as the system is one-dimensional. I feel like I'm going nowhere with this. Any suggestions? Am I on the right track?

EDIT: here is my attempt.
The HJ equation reads $\partial_tS + H(q, \partial_qS, t) = 0$. With $S(q, t) = a(t)b(q)$, we have
$$
\dot{a}b + q^2a^2b'^2t = 0 \implies -\frac{\dot{a}}{a^2t} = \frac{q^2b'^2}{b}
$$
Introducing the sepration constant $k$, we have
\begin{cases}
-\frac{\dot{a}}{a^2t} = k \\
\frac{q^2b'^2}{b} = k
\end{cases}
Here is where I'm stuck, because I get two integration constants, say $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$. Then, there are two more constants of motion, namely $\beta_i = \partial_{\alpha_i}S, i =1, 2$. Do I need them to determine $k$ maybe? I think there are two many constants for me to relate them to the initial conditions $(q_0, p_0)$.

EDIT 2: following Qmechanic's hint, I set
$$
-\frac{\partial_tS}{t} = \alpha^2 = (q \partial_qS)^2
$$
From the first equality, I get $S = -\frac{\alpha^2t^2}{2} + f(q)$. Substituing into the second one, I get $f(q) = \alpha \log(q)$. From here, the solution is straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the separation of variable trick on the HJ equation: $$-\frac{\partial_t S}{t} ~=~\alpha^2~=~ (q\partial_qS)^2.$$

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. Thanks! I'll post my solution when I'm done working out all the details.